# How use jquery (or other external libraries) in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, visual-studio-code

As an exercise in learning Typescript, I am converting the javascript for a current project.
The project is served with flask, and edited with VSCode. I would very much like to use Typescript on the javascript parts, mostly for the improved intellisense and type checking in VSCode.

I have @types/jquery installed through npm, and if I have `import $ from "jquery"` in my .ts file then all is well, no errors in VSCode. But when I compile the code with tsc and run the site in chrome, the `import $ from "jquery"` in my javascript code gives a 'Failed to resolve module specifier "jquery"' in the chrome console. If I comment out that javascript line, no errors.

So, my question is: how do you use Typescript with an external library, loaded from CDN with a script tag, without getting import errors in your complied javascript code?

It seems like there should be a better way than going back through all my compiled code and commenting out the imports for the external libraries.

```js
# This code looks the same in both the.ts and.js file,
# but it gives a 'Failed to resolve module specifier "jquery"'
# error when the .js is run in my project.
# If I comment out the import in the .ts file, 
# the .ts has error -Cannot find name '$'- and will not compile.
# If I comment out the import in the compiled .js file, the page loads fine.
import $ from "jquery"

function foo() {
  $('#some-element')
}
```

```html
<!-- jquery is loaded from CDN -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

first install jquery through npm:

```
npm i jquery
```

and then

```
import $ from "jquery";
```

and use it

Comment: So how about an external library that wasn't written with TypeScript in mind, like https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/connect.boostlingo.com/sdk/boostlingo-js/1.0.3/dist/boostlingo.min.js?